# How do we specify our configuration for vim without editing vimrc?

Tags: vim, root

Since I am not the root user I cannot edit the /etc/vimrc file. I need to specify some vim parameters for my account.
for example

set number;

how can i set these variables to my user account configuration for vim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `~/.vimrc`.

Answer (score 0):

you can edit your own .vimrc file, then save it to ~/.vimrc